# How to access class properties from child context

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

When I need to access the class properties (or methods) from within a different scope, I have to assign it to a variable from within the function scope.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(API) {
        this.API = API;
        this.property = 'value';
    }

    myMethod() {
        var myClass = this; // I have to assign the class to a local variable

        this.API.makeHttpCall().then(function(valueFromServer) {
            // accessing via local variable
            myClass.property = valueFromServer;
        });
    }
}
```

This is something I'd rather not have to do for every method. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use an arrow function, it will preserve the value of `this`.

Comment: `this.API.makeHttpCall.call(this).then(...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is - use arrow functions:

```
class MyClass 
{
    private API;
    private property;

    constructor(API) 
    {
        this.API = API;
        this.property = 'value';
    }

    public myMethod() 
    {
        API.makeHttpCall().then((valueFromServer) => 
        {
            // accessing via local variable
            this.property = valueFromServer;
        });
    }
}
```